# QMultiMap And QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmap, qmultimap

I saw in QtAssistant that QDataStream supports QMap and QMultiMap inherits QMap . Does Qt support QMultiMap for serialization with QDataStream ?

Comment: what happens when you try? what specific problem do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but it should. QMultiMap doesn't fundamentally change anything about QMap. Even a regular QMap can handle multiple values with the same key. QMultiMap just provides a few extra convenience functions.

I'd also note that the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.5/qmultimap.html) doesn't mention anything about any incompatabilities, even claiming that

> Because QMultiMap inherits QMap, all
>   of QMap's functionality also applies
>   to QMultiMap.